# When using html to get a user file input (specifically an image), how do I then save that file locally?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload

I have a website built with html, javascript, and java for a college project, and part of it has an html form which takes user input, & creates a new webpage using those inputs. It all works fine, except for when the user inputs an image. The entire thing is hosted locally on my laptop using a Tomcat server through eclipse.

I have this code snippet

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-center">
  <form action="NewProjectLoadingPage.jsp" method="POST">
    <h4>Choose an image to include</h4>
    <p>
      <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </form>
```

which allows the user to search their computer for an image and 'upload it' except I have no idea how to then save the image with a specific name to a specific folder on my computer so that when the new page is created, it can find the image and display it.
(is this a good idea for a real site? definitely not, but for this college project I really need this to work & this site isn't going to be hosted online any time soon)

I haven't been able to find any tutorials for this kind of thing specifically, but if anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it, & if you

Comment: That's the server's job. Browsers (safe ones) do not have access to your file system by default. Some browser's (such as Chrome) offer such access after being explicitly allowed by the user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many tutorials on how to manage image uploads. You didn't specify what backend language you're using but I'll guess Java. Search the internet for how to manage image uploads with Java (or whatever language you're using)